# How can I find out what the highest block is?

Tags: nodes, synchronization

I'm syncing up a new node. How can I find out what the latest block is so that I know how far I've got to go?

Comment: I have started to sync since 15 days ago and today I think I passed the highest block 4741144 I downloaded 4741185 of 4741144 but ethereum node started to downloaded chain data. does anybody know how many chain structure needs to download to full sync. my computer already downloaded about 10 M chain structure after reaching to highest block.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For Geth, in another terminal, attach to the Geth console, such as `geth attach`.  This will allow you to keep your syncing node running, without restarting, and you will not see the noisy logs as you would if you simply ran "geth console" without other parameters.

In the console, run `eth.syncing`

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 745600,
  highestBlock: 889152,
  startingBlock: 745553
}
```

You can then see where you are (currentBlock), and the block you still have to reach (highestBlock).  (The difference between them is the number of blocks you have left remaining.)

You can run `eth.syncing` a few times to check your progress, and it will return `false` when done.  You can then use `eth.blockNumber` and also compare with a blockchain explorer, as other answers here mention.

For clarity `web3.eth.isSyncing()` will also return `false` when syncing has not yet started (or is currently not running).  If this is the case, you need to check your networking that you are connecting to peers: [Why doesn't my Ethereum node have any peers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53/why-doesnt-my-ethereum-node-have-any-peers)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just note that `geth attach` doesn't work if you have the `--mine` flag specified (for test chains) so if you use that you should also probably use a mining script

Comment: I use `geth` version 1.4.6 and `eth.syncing` just returns `true` or `false`. What's the new version of the `eth.syncing` command?

Comment: @TMOTTM It might be a bug and I suggest "New issue" at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues

Comment: more info was added to the output but this is still a valid way to check.

Comment: Function `web3.eth.isSyncing()` will return `false` **also** when syncing has not yet started (or is currently not running). So one cannot rely solely on this function in order to determine the status of the Ethereum client. As you mentioned, probably need to combine the results of `web3.eth.getBlockNumber()` and a blockchain explorer into the decision-making.

Comment: `eth.blockNumber` gives me `0`

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks I added parts of your comment to the answer. Hope you are well.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Geth:

```
geth attach http://host
```

then enter:

```
web3.eth.blockNumber
```

It will give you the block number as integer, here's the [function documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethblocknumber). If you are looking for the block hash instead you can use:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(BLOCK_NUMBER).hash
```

so for the current block (atm) it will be:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(887893).hash
```

and for the latest block:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).hash
```

In the latest version of web3 you can use `getBlockNumber()` which returns a promise (thx @PaulRBerg for mentioning that)

Comment: I added an answer because simple re-run with "geth console" will have noisy logs interfering with the console; and eth.syncing provides more info.

Comment: In versions 1.0.0 and above, `blockNumber` has been renamed to `getBlockNumber` and it returns a promise.

Answer (score 8):

there are 2 usefull scripts in https://github.com/lyricalpolymath/Ethereum-Scripts

- 1) [show simple progress %](https://github.com/lyricalpolymath/Ethereum-Scripts/blob/master/GethSyncingProgress_1Simple.js)

with geth running, copy and paste this code in a terminal window to have a simple feedback of the blockchain syncing progress

```
geth --exec 'var s = eth.syncing; console.log("\n------------ GETH SYNCING PROGRESS\nprogress: " + (s.currentBlock/s.highestBlock*100)+ " %\nblocks left to parse: "+ (s.highestBlock-s.currentBlock) + "\ncurrent Block: " + s.currentBlock + " of " + s.highestBlock)' attach
```

you will get an output like this

```
------------ GETH SYNCING PROGRESS 
progress: 81.9161292631709 % 
blocks left to parse: 368837 
current Block: 1670754 of 2039591
```

---

- 2) [advance progress with Time Estimate](https://github.com/lyricalpolymath/Ethereum-Scripts/blob/master/GethSyncingProgress_2TimeEstimate.js)

download the script and with geth running, copy and paste this code in a terminal window to have a simple feedback of the blockchain syncing progress

```
geth --exec "loadScript('GethSyncingProgress_2TimeEstimate.js')" attach
```

will give you an output like

```
------------ GETH SYNCING PROGRESS - Time estimate
progress: 83.83513931320763
Estimated Time left*: 7d :11h :4m :4s.3
Time it took to parse 10 blocks: 0d :0h :0m :19s.5
blocks left to parse: 330536
```

Comment: Combine this with `watch` to get an updating feed:
`watch -n 10 "geth --exec 'var s = eth.syncing; console.log(\"\n------------ GETH SYNCING PROGRESS\nprogress: \" + (s.currentBlock/s.highestBlock*100)+ \" %\nblocks left to parse: \"+ (s.highestBlock-s.currentBlock) + \"\ncurrent Block: \" + s.currentBlock + \" of \" + s.highestBlock)' attach"
`

Answer (score 7):

You could use a block explorer, such as [Etherchain](https://etherchain.org/).

Answer (score 5):

The [Ethereum wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) will display the latest block number. The official [Ethereum stats](https://ethstats.net/) website also displays it. (Note: this doesn't represent all peers on the network.)

Comment: Note: It's 'mist browser' or 'ethereum wallet'. But there is no such thing as a 'mist wallet'. :)

Comment: https://stats.ethdev.com/ doesn't respond

Comment: I fixed the link.

Answer (score 3):

`web3.eth.blockNumber` gets you the latest block height on your node. Note that you have to have a synced node for that. When you are still downloading the blockchain this number will be smaller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still syncing you can type eth.syncing and it will report

- currentBlock
- highestBlock
- startingBlock

If eth.syncing is false then use the eth.blockNumber command sebastian mentioned and compare it to the reported block height from your favorite online block explorer

Comment: so `syncing===false` doesn't guarantee that geth is in sync? if you provide an example of an online block explorer and how to retrieve the reported block height from it, I'll upvote your answer

Comment: I guess this one will do http://testnet.etherscan.io/

Answer (score 1):

web3.eth.getBlock('latest').then(function(x){console.log(x.timestamp)});

Answer (score 1):

I use the JSON RPC to check from another machine (assuming access). Replace 0.0.0.0:8545 with th RPC address and port of the machine running GETH with RPC.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' 0.0.0.0:8545
```

returns

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":69,"result":{"currentBlock":"0x767811","highestBlock":"0x767879","knownStates":"0x8ba1951","pulledStates":"0x8ba0752","startingBlock":"0x5a95a1"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was annoyed because `eth.syncing` returns `false` even before the syncing starts (and it also returns `false` after the sync *finished*, so there's no way to tell).

A different way to go about it, if you don't need the actual block number: you can compare your latest synced block's timestamp with the current time:

`Date.now()/1000 - eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp`

If this amount is greater than, say, 2 minutes (`120`), then it's very likely that you don't have the last blocks.