# Why does my account balance show zero?

Tags: balances

I downloaded the new ethereum wallet yesterday. I deleted everything in the folder: chain data, I resynced the whole blockchain aswell.

But now when I open the wallet, my balance shows zero... when I enter it's address on etherchain it shows the right balance... which is larger than zero.

Any help how to resolve this pls?

Comment: Are you still synchronizing the blockchain?

Comment: How do you mean? It synced to the present?

Comment: Check http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/394/how-can-i-find-out-what-the-highest-block-is to find out about `eth.syncing` and `eth.blockNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if your keystore has a txt document inside of it with the corresponding keystore values of your wallet. if there are no keystore values, your account balance will read zero.