# Intermittent Synchronisation failed: no peers to keep download active?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

My geth blockchain sync is stalling with the error message:

```
I0323 07:46:09.085264 3027 downloader.go:267] Synchronisation failed: no peers to keep download active
```

I've tried to restart it but it syncs again for a while and then stalls again, it seems to repeat this pattern.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I guess its the problem with latency

Comment: Have you tried updating your clock? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53/why-doesnt-my-ethereum-node-have-any-peers

Comment: Is this resolved?  Are you using testnet or mainnet?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to sync with testnet, there seems to not be many peers running on this testnet. I got the same errors, but just restarted `geth` and eventually the blockchain was synced.

I've not encountered this problem on mainnet. Please reply / edit your question if you did encounter this issue on mainnet and we can try to work through this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've got these errors too from time to time with 3 ethereum nodes (1 instance in Windows 10, another instance on Ubuntu 16 and another one on CentOS) running geth on mainnet. Waiting for a while use to fix it. If the error takes too long to disappear, restarting geth fixes it too.