# In geth, `eth.syncing` gives `false` even when blocks are imported

Tags: go-ethereum

I issue `eth.syncing` and get `false` even when at the same time blocks are imported. Is this correct behaviour?

Using geth version 1.4.6

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, correct behavior.  `false` means that your Geth is up to date and is not currently syncing.  It keeps importing the latest block to remain up to date.  Check `eth.blockNumber` against a block explorer if you want to double-check.

EDIT: `web3.eth.isSyncing()` will also return `false` when syncing has not yet started (or is currently not running).  If this is the case, you need to check your networking that you are connecting to peers: [Why doesn't my Ethereum node have any peers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53/why-doesnt-my-ethereum-node-have-any-peers)

Comment: The `eth.syncing` or `web3.eth.syncing` returns `false`, while `eth.blockNumber` returns `0`. It doesn't seem correct at all.

Comment: @Raptor I'm not sure so I suggest asking a separate question.

Comment: `eth.blockNumber` says `0` for me

Comment: @chovy I am editing the questions that you have made comments to. Maybe you are not getting any peers.