# How long is the first sync supposed to last?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, nodes

I've been running Geth (latest version) for around 12 hours and it's still not finished.

The command prompt shows this :

```
INFO [05-21|12:05:00] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=9   mgas=0.748 elapsed=40.047ms   mgasps=18.687 number=3742904 hash=f8fd6e…fce9f8

INFO [05-21|12:05:29] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=2   mgas=0.044 elapsed=16.018ms   mgasps=2.741  number=3742905 hash=04b0be…3d64cd

INFO [05-21|12:05:38] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=66  mgas=2.851 elapsed=95.126ms   mgasps=29.971 number=3742906 hash=157014…c50cc5
```

By the way, my Internet speed isn't that bad, check it out

[image: Internet Speed]

Is this normal ? Should I try using another client such as Parity ?

PS : I've run Geth using this command line : `geth --fast --cache=1024`

Comment: Last time I tried it took 2-3 days.

Comment: Do you know which number I'm supposed to reach ?
Right now I'm at "number=3743185"

Comment: Then you are done. Check against etherscan.io

Comment: Another day, I executed the synchronization with the command `geth attach` that dont work out today.  So, I tried `geth --fast --cache=1024` and this is working.

Comment: For your information, at this moment (2018-11-29), I tried `--syncmode=full --gcmode=archive`. After about 18 hours I reached block 2702327. The highest block is 6799556.

Answer (score 41):

Do following steps to check the sync state:

1.) open a new geth instance and type in `geth attach`
2.) now type in `eth.syncing`

This shows you the "currentBlock" and the "highestBlock".

Comment: What does that even mean? Should they be the same, or near each other?

Comment: They should be close to each other. In other words, run `100 * eth.syncing.currentBlock / eth.syncing.highestBlock` to get the percent completed. When it is close to 100, you are synced.

Comment: If eth.syncing is false, it's already sync and you can check `eth.blockNumber` against a block explorer if you want to double-check. [Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6525/23349)

Comment: So it should be CLOSE or EXACT the same number of block? It's crucial

Because I'm 99.99335% synced and I'm wating for hour still on the same block. I wonder am I synced or not yet.

Comment: Fun fact: `geth attach` is actually a complete JavaScript environment! If you're looking to repeatedly print out the percentage on a timed loop, you can simply run `(function percentage() { console.log(100* eth.syncing.currentBlock / eth.syncing.highestBlock); setTimeout(percentage, 10000); } ());`

Answer (score 10):

I think you should edit the question to ask, "How do I know when geth is done syncing?"

The question you asked was vague, but I believe this is the answer you were after:

Geth will continue running forever. Once it is "done", it will just sit there and wait for the next block. The "numbers" you refer to are block numbers, and they shall increment for all of eternity. Once your *current* block reaches the *highest* block, you are all synced up. As mentioned by 5chdn, the highest block  can be determined by checking someplace such as etherscan.io.

I let Geth run for hours thinking that I was waiting for it to "finish" when in fact it had been done for a long time.  As of this writing, the highest block is 3854270

Thanks to 5chdn's comment which was really the key to the answer.

Comment: So do we just stop it once it's in sync? Wouldn't that put it out of sync because it wouldn't have the latest blocks?

Comment: It will be in sync until the next block is released. You can stop it, but yes that means that you will fall out of sync eventually. If you want to always stay up-to-date, then you can leave it running. The point being, the app is never "done", per se. But it does come to a point where it is all "caught up", for the time-being.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are using a Linux flavoured OS, you can check the sync status as well (run this as the user under which geth is running):

```
$ geth --exec eth.syncing.currentBlock attach
3991639
```

If it's not syncing, it will only display 'false'.

Or, if you want to get a little more fancy and see how many blocks / second are syncing, here is an idea:

```
A=$(geth --exec eth.syncing.currentBlock attach)
while true; do
  echo "Currently at block ${A}"
  sleep 1
  B=$(geth --exec eth.syncing.currentBlock attach);
  echo "Reached block ${B}"
  echo "$B-$A"|bc; A=$B
done
```

Answer (score 5):

If you start geth with "--verbosity 5", it will print out a bunch of debug info. It won't speed things up, but it will let you know that geth is not hung.

I think what people do is run geth. It starts churning on something. They wait and wait. And then they kill geth because it appears hung. If you do that, geth will just have to start that long process over again taking it even that much longer to sync.

Verbosity 5 lets you have the patience to let it run until it finishes because you can see that it's not hung.

Comment: Well the numbers keep increasing, right now I'm at "number=3744194". So I don't think it's stuck. Thanks tho, I'll remember that option next time I launch geth :)

Comment: verbosity level 5 will significantly slow down your import process. do not change it, just check the import status with javascript console

Comment: You can turn verbosity on and off. I’m suggesting you turn it on during the DDos attack so you know that the node is not hung. If you constantly kill the node because you think it’s hung, it’s going to restart on the same transaction that it was processing previously and take that much longer.

Answer (score 3):

```
INFO [05-22|08:14:16] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1   txs=2    mgas=0.067  elapsed=11.000ms  mgasps=6.104   number=3745188 hash=9b8973…920c7e
```

Has been running for about 32 hours. Ran Geth with `geth --rpc --fast -cache=1024`

Ethereum folder size: 17.9Gb

Comment: Note, fast is deprecated and also now default. `--syncmode` is the new switch for sync behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember that. And I also noticed that I had -cache instead of --cache. Restarted the sync last night and up to number=3753194.. Alot better.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I believe my blockchain is up to date and I didn't realize until I compared where my geth client was at compared to the network status for Eth.  
So I'm up to here:
INFO [05-29|23:07:27] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1   txs=8    mgas=0.168   elapsed=19.999ms  mgasps=8.400   number=3786778

And checking https://ethstats.net/ I can see I have the latest and am even one block ahead.
So I'm basically ready to start mining now. I believe I was actually up to date a few days ago but didn't know being new.

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer using Parity because of the snapshot feature they have. Using a GCE cloud instance I was able to sync the full chain in 30 minutes.

Here is an explanation of how it works :
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Warp-Sync-Snapshot-Format