# New to coin just starting out

Tags: transactions, mist

I am sorry for my insuficient knowledge of cryptocurrency world but i thought hey why not. I bought a 100euro worth of ether from Bitpanda. I opened Ethereum wallet and created a main account which had a long key, which i presume is my wallet address. I pasted that into Bitpanda when checking out. Now i don't know if i messed up by pasting that key as the destination. Syncing is taking me ages and in between a create a contract popup poped up. :) it said something about mileage which i had absolutely no knowledge about what it does. So guys did i loose my 100eur?:)

Comment: You don't have to sync, just check your account balance using  [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/).

Comment: The comment "You don't have to sync" should be tempered with "if you're okay relying on someone else for your security." Otherwise, you're completing ignore the distinguishing characteristic of the whole thing: decentralization.

Comment: It is good to have more nodes running to have good decentralization. That being said, I do not see how not running a local node decreases my security. The Ethereum mainnet is still decentralized whether a particular individual runs a node or not.

Comment: It doesn't decrease overall system-wide security, but it does decrease your individual security. You're relying on the third party to get your data.  I'm not saying you shouldn't, just that you shouldn't do so without thinking about it which 'jeff's' original comment above seems to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

If you've installed a wallet (Mist for example), and generated an external account address, and you have that address, you can double check that the transaction went through by using an explorer such as http://etherscan.io. Just enter your account there, and you will see your transaction if it went through.

But, also, if you have a local node running (which you do if you've installed Mist or Parity), then eventually you should see the transaction appear in that wallet. It may take a very long time for the 'node' to sync however, so you have to be patient. [Check out this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16393/how-long-is-the-first-sync-supposed-to-last/16398#16398)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the Bitpanda process, but the [Ethereum Block Explorer](https://etherscan.io/) may be of use to you.

You can use it to view transactions to your wallet address.