# Long wait for syncing the chain with Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, synchronization, fast-sync

I have been following some advice here on how to sync the chain using Geth (`geth --cache=XXXX --fast`).

Yet I have been waiting for more than 24 hours for things to sync.  Currently, it is at about 14 GB of chain data and still going.

How large is the chain using `--fast` as of May of 2017?

Also is it normal for the process to take that long on fast storage (100 MB/s write speeds, ~180 MB/s read), with 400 MBit/s downstream and eight CPU threads at 4.6 GHz?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16393/how-long-is-the-first-sync-supposed-to-last/16398#16398

Comment: Nop neither of these. 48 hours and still waiting.

Comment: So after some more investigation and a complete removal of all old chain data it now syncs really fast. IO Speed seems to be the most crucial part here, even the speeds shown above are not enough, the more IOPS and R/W the better (-> NVMe).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://etherscan.io/  - ~ 3794099

Faster hard drive helps for syncing the block chain.