# How to check sync status

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

How can I check simplest way am I synced with blockchain? When I executed geth attach command and typed in:

```
100 * eth.syncing.currentBlock / eth.syncing.highestBlock
```

The outcome sounds about 99.99335...

For an hour I'm waiting on the same block which is not equal to highest block. Should I still wait or am I already synced an I'm able to start mining?

Comment: `eth.syncing` will give you current block and highest block.

Comment: Yes. It's currentBlock: 4664002, highestBlock: 4664130. Does it mean is it unsynced? Because here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16393/how-long-is-the-first-sync-supposed-to-last
They said it have to be CLOSE to 100% to be in sync. I'd like to confirm it.

Comment: The sync only depends on if you have latest block.  If somebody sends you some ethers and this transaction was included in block 4664006 and your current block is 4664002 , then you will not see this transaction on your node and your balance is updated on entire blockchain but your node. So you need to sync all blocks. Close to 100% can be said as almost synced but not completely synced.

Comment: How much is your size in data. As of now?