# JSON-RPC command to get blockchain synchronization status

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, json-rpc, testnets, morden

Is there some `json-rpc` command, so that I can get the `blockchain` synchronization status from `geth`.

I am trying to connect to the `--testnet` using get. Its taking forever to connect to the `testnet`, are there some reliable nodes to which I can connect to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JSON-RPC there's [`eth_syncing`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_syncing):

```
// Request
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}'

// Result
{
  "id":1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    startingBlock: '0x384',
    currentBlock: '0x386',
    highestBlock: '0x454'
  }
}
// Or when not syncing
{
  "id":1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": false
}
```

Geth is hardcoded with bootstrap nodes for testnet which should be among the most reliable.  Make sure that your clock is in sync and check [Why doesn't my Ethereum node have any peers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53/why-doesnt-my-ethereum-node-have-any-peers).