# net.peerCount is Zero and blockNumber has stuck

Tags: go-ethereum

I had a problem that my blockNumber gets stuck. Then I ran `geth upgradedb` and started `geth --rpc --mine console` again.

It looked like it was working, had the correct blockNumber for around 30 minutes and had `net.peerCount = 1`.

And now again, `net.peerCount = 0`, the blockNumber has stopped updating and it doesn't get synced...

Answer (score 2):

Check this similar question and answer that might give you some hints on how to proceed.

[Why doesn't my Ethereum node have any peers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53/why-doesnt-my-ethereum-node-have-any-peers)